# How can Kotlin deduce this 'is' as Account type?

Tags: kotlin

The following Code A is from the main branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab).

In Code A, two 'it' are deduced as `Account` type , and also 'account' is deduced as `Account` type.

How can Kotlin deduce? You know `private fun <T> OverviewScreenCard(...)` is generic , and `T` maybe is any type.

BTW, I think that I should use Code B instead of Code A.

**Code A**

```
@Composable
private fun AccountsCard(onClickSeeAll: () -> Unit, onAccountClick: (String) -> Unit) {
    val amount = UserData.accounts.map { account -> account.balance }.sum()
    OverviewScreenCard(
        title = stringResource(R.string.accounts),
        amount = amount,
        onClickSeeAll = onClickSeeAll,
        data = UserData.accounts,
        colors = { it.color },     //  This 'it' is Account type
        values = { it.balance }    //  This 'it' is Account type
    ) { account ->                 //  This 'account' is Account type  
        AccountRow(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { onAccountClick(account.name) },
            name = account.name,
            number = account.number,
            amount = account.balance,
            color = account.color
        )
    }
}


@Composable
private fun <T> OverviewScreenCard(
    title: String,
    amount: Float,
    onClickSeeAll: () -> Unit,
    values: (T) -> Float,
    colors: (T) -> Color,
    data: List<T>,
    row: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    ...
    
}


@Composable
fun AccountRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    name: String,
    number: Int,
    amount: Float,
    color: Color
) {
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
private fun AccountsCard(onClickSeeAll: () -> Unit, onAccountClick: (String) -> Unit) {
    val amount = UserData.accounts.map { account -> account.balance }.sum()
    OverviewScreenCard<Account>(                          //I think I need use this
        title = stringResource(R.string.accounts),
        ...
    ) { account ->
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `UserData.accounts`?

Comment: `UserData.accounts` is `List<Account>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, none of the parameters you have passed to `OverviewScreenCard` constrains `T` in any way, ***except***

```
data = UserData.accounts
```

`UserData.accounts` is of type `List<Account>`. On the right hand side, the `data` parameter is expecting a `List<T>`. This constrains what `T` can be. `T` can only be `Account`, or a super type of `Account`. Otherwise, you wouldn't have been able to pass `UserData.accounts` to the `data` parameter.

And since the other parameters you have passed does not constrain the type of `T` further, the compiler resolves the constraints on `T` and chooses the most specific type that satisfies them, which is `Account`.

You can also specify the type directly like you do in Code B, but it is redundant.